# Why is mouse position incorrect?

Tags: assembly, mouse-position

I use `Windows 8.1` and an emulator for assembly `8086`.

I want to design a program in assembly that draws 4 squares and when user clicks on each of them paints this. For example I draw square in position (50,50) to (100,100) pixel, but when click on square, mouse position incorrect, for example 150, while end of square on 100 Pixel.

```
macro mosPos 

  local L  

   mov ax, 1
   int 33h

 L:mov ax, 3
   int 33h
   cmp bx, 1
   jne L

   mov XMouse, cx
   mov YMouse, dx

endm
```

Comment: is this graphics or text mode? In text mode the grid size is small such as but the mouse position resolution still accurate to pixel, so you need to divide by the character size to get the correct coordinates

Comment: anyway, in text mode resolution is rather limited, the maximum I've ever seen is 80x25 so I think this is graphics mode

Comment: tank u
i find answer.